# Creating a Resources.Load variable to use with multiple buttons

Tags: unity-game-engine, instantiation

Okay, I've been stuck in a rabbit hole on this for awhile now and I need some insight. I'm trying to create a little script that I can attach to a button that on press instantiates an image. I'm locked up on how to create a public GameObject field in the editor where I can drag a unique Image prefab into the editor (for each button). I'm lost right now. I originally wrote it with an explicit prefab in Resources.Load() but now I need to abstract it so I can use it with a few dozen buttons.

```
Vector3 symbolScale = new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
public GameObject symbolPrefabObj = Resources.Load(symbolPrefab);
GameObject symbolCharacter;


public void OnPointerClick (PointerEventData eventData)
{
    // Instantiate an object on Click
    symbolCharacter = Instantiate(symbolPrefabObj, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    symbolCharacter.transform.parent = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MessagePanel").transform;
    symbolCharacter.transform.localScale = symbolScale;
}
```

This is the original code (below) that I wrote, and it works for a single instance, but like I mentioned I want to drop this code onto dozens ot buttons and assign each button a different image prefab in the editor.

```
Vector3 symbolScale = new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
GameObject symbolCharacter;

#region IPointerClickHandler implementation

public void OnPointerClick (PointerEventData eventData)
{
    // Instantiate an object on Click
    symbolCharacter = Instantiate(Resources.Load ("Prefabs/Symbols/SymbolImage1"), new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    symbolCharacter.transform.parent = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MessagePanel").transform;
    symbolCharacter.transform.localScale = symbolScale;
}
```

Comment: looks like you should make `GameObject symbolPrefabObj` a parameter of the method, and `GameObject symbolCharacter` the return value. you can then also make the method static, and then, for example, have one global field per `GameObject symbolCharacter*`, and call the function for each of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this:

```
public string imageName;

symbolCharacter = Instantiate(Resources.Load (Path.Combine("Prefabs/Symbols", imageName)), new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
```

Now you can attach this script to many gameObjects with different imageName since `imageName` is a public variable.